# Validity of shorter path to $\ln {2n \choose n} \leq \sum_{p\leq 2n} \left \lfloor \frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln p}\right \rfloor \ln p $ for Chebyshev Estimates

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In proving the Chebyshev approximations for the prime counting function $\pi(x)$, several textbooks and papers (eg [pdf](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Efranz/nt/cheb.pdf), and also Stopple) use the following statement early in the derivation of the lower bound:

$$ 2n\ln2 - \ln(2n) \leq \sum_{p\leq 2n} \left \lfloor \frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln p}\right \rfloor \ln p $$

Those sources take several steps and a couple of lemmas to reach this point.

**Question:** I think I have a shorter route. Is my route valid, and if not, where is the error?

---

**Step 1:**

By examining the binomial coefficients of $(1+1)^{2n}$ we can see that the average is $\leq$ the largest coefficient:

$$ \frac{2^{2n}}{2n} \leq {2n \choose n}$$

Taking logs:

$$ 2n\ln2 - \ln(2n) \leq \ln {2n \choose n} $$

---

**Step 2:**

Thinking about the prime factorisation of ${2n \choose n}$, we can say that all the prime factors $p$ will have an integer power $m_p$ such that $m_p \leq \lfloor \frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln{p}} \rfloor $. If $m_p$ was larger, then $p^{m_p}>2n$ which isn't possible.

To see this more clearly:
$$ {2n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1} $$

The largest term is $(2n)$ and so no prime factor $p$ can be larger than this.

The floor function $\lfloor \rfloor$ is applied to $\frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln{p}}$ because $m_p$ must be an integer, and cannot be larger than $\frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln{p}}$.

---

**Step 3:**

The rest of the proof can proceed, with the following establishing an inequality for $\pi(2n)$.

$$\begin{align} 2n\ln2 - \ln(2n) &\leq \ln {2n \choose n} \\ \\ &\leq \sum_{p\leq 2n} \left \lfloor \frac{\ln(2n)}{\ln p}\right \rfloor \ln p  \\ \\ &\leq \sum_{p \leq 2n} \ln(2n)\\ \\  &= \ln(2n)\cdot \pi(2n)  \end{align}$$

---

**Notes:**

Since several sources require additional lemmas, I feel I must have missed a key step, or oversimplified.

These lemmas include:

- $v_p(n!) = \sum_{m\geq1}\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^m} \right \rfloor$
- $ \lfloor 2x\rfloor - 2\lfloor x\rfloor \in {0,1} $

I would appreciate answers and comments suitable for readers not trained to university level mathematics.

Comment: Why isn't $p^m>2n$ possible?

Comment: There ar $2n+1$ terms to $(1+1)^{2n},$ but you can fudge that to get a denominator of $2n$ rather $2n+1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - yes you are correct.

Comment: @runway44 because in the expansion $\frac{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n+1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\ldots \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$ any factors must be between $(2n)$ and $(n+1)$. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Any prime factors of $\binom{2n}{n}$ must be between $2n$ and $n+1$, but $p^m$ isn't prime, it's a prime *power*, and a prime power divisor of $\binom{2n}{n}$ comes from multiplying *multiple* prime power divisors of *multiple* numbers from $\{n+1,\cdots,2n\}$, in general. How do you guarantee the *product* of the prime power divisors of the numbers from $n+1$ to $2n$ doesn't exceed $2n$? You *do* need to argue with the denominators too, for instance for $n=3$, the product $(4)(5)(6)$ is divisible by $2^3>6$, it is only after cancellation with $(1)(2)(3)$ the power of $2$ no longer exceeds $6$

Comment: @runway44 thanks - you corrected a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. If anyone is interested I've written up an walk-through of Lemmermayer's proof https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/04/chebyshevs-estimates-for-pix.html. Any errors are mine, and I'd welcome corrections.

Comment: What is the reference of the book from which you give a link to chapter 8 ?  thank you!

Comment: @RenéGy I'm afraid I don't know, I only found the ch8 via internet search, and looking at the author's home page doesn't suggest which book it comes from